# Enable scroll within a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When I use `scrollWheel` I'm incremeting the `currentSlide` by one, when `currentSlide === 2` the red div is going up and I want to enable the scrolling to the body. As you see my bind function is returning `false`. I tried to put conditions on that and `return true` when `currentSlide === 2` but apparently it won't work.

Can anybody explain to me how to fix that?

```
var currentSlide = 0;

function scrollDown() {
    console.log('Scroll Down', currentSlide);      

  if(currentSlide < 3) {
    currentSlide += 1;                 
  }

  if(currentSlide === 3) {
    $('#el').addClass('hide');
  }
}
```

http://jsbin.com/rovicawija/1/edit?js,console,output

Comment: don't use bind. bind is deprecated. use on. first note after glancing at your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm totally not sure what you are trying to do as your question and expected result is quite unclear

I made the code as following

```
var currentSlide = 0;

    function scrollDown() {
        console.log('Scroll Down', currentSlide);      

      if(currentSlide < 10) {
        currentSlide += 1;                 
        return false;
      }

      if(currentSlide === 10) {
        $('#el').addClass('hide');
      }
    }


    $(window).on('DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
            if (e.originalEvent.detail > 0) {
                return scrollDown();
            } 


        })
        .on('mousewheel', function(e) {

            if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
                return scrollDown();
            }

        });
```

By using on(which you should) and having the scrollDown returning a boolean false if not good to go, and return nothing if there's nothing to do.

Comment: how can I scroll just on each .5s, I mean if I scroll too much I get to 10 too fast - ex: hugeinc.com

Comment: Save new Date().getTime() in a variable. Only execute `if(new Date().getTime() - previoustime >= 50){previoustime = new Date().getTime(); return scrollDown();}`

Answer (score 4):

Technically you are hiding the element when `currentSlide` is equal to 3 not 2.

Anyways instead of `return false;` in the bindings you will want to do `return currentSlide >= 3;` so that when the red div is hidden you can now scroll.

Also as someone else noted use `on` instead of `bind` because bind has been deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

I just put `return true` on the last function and everything seemed to work fine, see [here](http://jsbin.com/tuliki/1/edit?js,console,output):

```
$(window).bind('DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
        if (e.originalEvent.detail > 0) {
            scrollDown();
        }
        return false;
    })
    .bind('mousewheel', function(e) {
        if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
            scrollDown();
        }
        return true;
    });
```